# passing array as reference type node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am connecting to S3 and parsing a json file out,
I created a new object called Singer and an array of objects.
I would like to use this array of objects outside of the scope of the function

```
console.log("Loading up the best code ever!!!");

var fs = require('fs');
// Load the SDK for JavaScript
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile')
var Singer = require('./Singer')
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-west-1" });
var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials();
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;
// Create S3 service object
s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
console.log("after S3");


// Create the parameters for calling createBucket
var bucketParams = {
    Bucket: 'pc-backend-exercises',
    Key: 'toSearch.json',
    ResponseContentType: 'application/json'
};
s3.getObject(bucketParams, function (err, data) {
    // Handle any error and exit
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); 
        return err;
    }
    var fileContents = data.Body.toString();
    var json = JSON.parse(fileContents);
    console.log(json);

    var singers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < json.Search.artists.length; i++) {
        var newSinger = new Singer(json.Search.artists[i]);
        singers.push(newSinger);
    }


    console.log('Singers:');
    console.log(singers);


});

console.log('download json file from s3');
```

this code works fine. I get the output

```
Loading up the best code ever!!!
after S3
download json file from s3
{ Search: { artists: [ 'Katy', 'Madonna', 'Rihanna', 'Beyonce' ] } }
Singers:
[ Singer { name: 'Katy', songs: [] },
  Singer { name: 'Madonna', songs: [] },
  Singer { name: 'Rihanna', songs: [] },
  Singer { name: 'Beyonce', songs: [] } ]
```

however what I change my code to pass the array singers by reference it doesn't work.

```
var singers = [];
s3.getObject(bucketParams, function (err, data, singers) {
    // Handle any error and exit
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); 
        return err;
    }
    var fileContents = data.Body.toString();
    var json = JSON.parse(fileContents);
    console.log(json);


    for (var i = 0; i < json.Search.artists.length; i++) {
        var newSinger = new Singer(json.Search.artists[i]);
        singers.push(newSinger);
    }

});

console.log('Singers:');
console.log(singers);


console.log('download json file from s3');
```

the output is:

```
Loading up the best code ever!!!
after S3
Singers:
[]
download json file from s3
{ Search: { artists: [ 'Katy', 'Madonna', 'Rihanna', 'Beyonce' ] } }
C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\Node\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
        at Response.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\Node\gili.js:38:17)
        at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\Node\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:364:18)
        at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\Node\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:105:20)
        at Request.emit (C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\Node\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:77:10)
        at Request.emit (C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\Node\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)
        at Request.transition (C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\Node\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
        at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\Node\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
        at C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\Node\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
        at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\Node\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
        at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gdarmon\Desktop\Node\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:685:12)
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here.

## The error message

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Look here:

> ```
> s3.getObject(bucketParams, function (err, data, singers) {
> ```

`singers` is undefined because you have defined an argument called `singers` (which masks the variable in the wider scope). The `getObject` function, when it calls the anonymous function you pass to it, doesn't give the third argument a value.

I have no idea why you expect it to.

If you remove that argument, then you will have access to the `singers` variable in the wider scope again.

## Order of execution

This is a FAQ. See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) which is probably in the top 3 targets for "Close as duplicate" on all of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is scope of the variables.
You have defined same variable name in local as well as global.

Change the local variable name and it should work I have changes as `singers1`

```
var singers = [];
s3.getObject(bucketParams, function (err, data, singers1) {
```

Comment: Why define it at all if it isn't going to be used?

Comment: Yes, it is not using, I have just gave hint for the issue, he can remove it